# Could the following partial differnential equations system have local solutions on plane?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Here are two unknown functions $u(x,y)$, $w(x,y)$ defined on plane, they satisfy
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta(u+w) &=0 \\
\lvert u_{x} \rvert^{2} + \lvert w_{x} \rvert^{2} &= \lvert u_{y} \rvert^{2} + \lvert w_{y} \rvert^{2} \\
u_{x} u_{y} + w_{x} w_{y} &= 0
\end{cases}
$$

could this PDE system exist some solutions locally?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $u=w=0$? $ $ $ $ $ $